# How to ensure Google Drive links in an html document sent via email are not recognized as attachments?

Tags: javascript, html, email, google-apps-script, gmail

I am using App Scripts to render an email in html that contains  tags whose href attributes link to Google Drive documents.

The App Script performs as expected, however when I open the emails sent in Gmail, all of the linked Google Drive documents show up as Attachments on the email.

How do I remove that functionality?

Currently using the following MailApp method:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddresses,
    noReply: true,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: htmlStr,
});
```

**EDIT:**

A less-than ideal solution would be to run the various google drive document links through a url-shortener like goog.le

Although this does get the job done in so far as the default gmail processes that recognize google drive document links are now no longer able to parse the google drive document links, I would prefer to be able to provide some header context that would inform the aforementioned default gmail processes to not parse google drive document links as attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried sending an email with the Html script as below:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1234546789123456789/edit#gid=0">link</a>
    <p>
      This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.


    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and it worked and displayed it as a href but not as an attachment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I do not know if the example `href` you included in your above `a` tag quite gets at the issue.  If the `href` were an actual google document, you would likely see the issue that is trying to be overcome.